# Download Multiple Items from Amazon S3 Bucket iOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've recently implemented the new AWS 2.0 iOS SDK in my application (yay, cocoapods!), and using the sample code from Amazon managed to properly configure access and downloads. I can successfully download a single item without issue, but I need to be able to download multiple files dynamically generated based on the current tableview. There doesn't appear to be a way to set up a batch download, so I'm simply trying to loop through an array of objects and trigger a download with each one. It works, but if the list includes more than a few items, it starts randomly misfiring. For example, if my dynamically created list has 14 items in it, 12 will be downloaded, and the other 2 aren't even attempted. The request just vanishes. In my testing, I added a sleep(1) timer, and then all 14 are triggered and downloaded, so I'm guessing that I'm overwhelming the download requests and they are getting dropped unless I slow it down. Slowing it down is not ideal... perhaps there is another way? Here is the code:

```
 - (IBAction)downloadAllPics:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
if (debug==1) {
    NSLog(@"Running %@ '%@'", self.class, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
}

CoreDataHelper *cdh =
[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] cdh];

// for loop iterates through all of the items in the tableview
for (Item *item in self.frc.fetchedObjects) {

    NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *downloadingFilePath1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@@2x.jpg",docDir, item.imageName];
    NSURL *downloadingFileURL1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:downloadingFilePath1];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error = nil;
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:downloadingFilePath1]) {
        fileAlreadyExists = TRUE;
        if (![fileManager removeItemAtPath:downloadingFilePath1
                                     error:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }
    }
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

    self.downloadRequest1 = [AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest new];
    self.downloadRequest1.bucket = S3BucketName;
    //  self.downloadRequest1.key = S3KeyDownloadName1;
    self.downloadRequest1.key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"images/%@@2x.jpg", item.imageName];
    self.downloadRequest1.downloadingFileURL = downloadingFileURL1;
    self.downloadRequest1.downloadProgress = ^(int64_t bytesWritten, int64_t totalBytesWritten, int64_t totalBytesExpectedToWrite){
        // update progress
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            weakSelf.file1AlreadyDownloaded = totalBytesWritten;
            weakSelf.file1Size = totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
        });

    };

     // this launches the actual S3 transfer manager - it is successfully launched with each pass of loop
    [self downloadFiles];
}

[cdh backgroundSaveContext];

 }
```

That launches the downloadFiles method:

```
 - (void) downloadFiles {
//if I add this sleep, all 14 download. If I don't usually 11-13 download.
sleep(1);
AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];

__block int downloadCount = 0;

[[transferManager download:self.downloadRequest1] continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
     if (task.error != nil){
        if(task.error.code != AWSS3TransferManagerErrorCancelled && task.error.code != AWSS3TransferManagerErrorPaused){
            NSLog(@"%s Errorx: [%@]",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__, task.error);
        }
    } else {
        self.downloadRequest1 = nil;

    }
    return nil;
}];        
 }
```

There has got to be a way to download a dynamic list of files from an Amazon S3 bucket, right? Maybe there is a transfer manager that allows an array of files instead of doing them individually?

Any and all help is appreciated.
Zack

Comment: Trying to do the same thing, would love to see someone answers this...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like request timeout interval setting issue.

First, when you configure `AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = ...` try to configure the `timeoutIntervalForRequest` property. Also, `maxRetryCount` as well. `maxRetryCount` will attempt to download if failure for downloading each operation.

```
AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:DefaultServiceRegionType
                                                                     credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];
[configuration setMaxRetryCount:2]; // 10 is the max
[configuration setTimeoutIntervalForRequest:120]; // 120 seconds
```

Second, for the multiple items downloading try to collect each `AWSTask` into one array and get the result at the end of group operation. ex)

```
// task collector
NSMutableSet *uniqueTasks = [NSMutableSet new];

// Loop
for (0 -> numOfDownloads) {
     AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest *downloadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest new];
     [downloadRequest setBucket:S3BucketNameForProductImage];
     [downloadRequest setKey:filename];
     [downloadRequest setDownloadingFileURL:sourceURL];
     [showroomGroupDownloadRequests addObject:downloadRequest];

    AWSTask *task = [[AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager] download:downloadRequest];
    [task continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
    // handle each individual operation
    if (task.error == nil) {

    }
    else if (task.error) {

    }
    // add to the tasks
    [uniqueTasks addObject:task];

    return nil;
}

[[AWSTask taskForCompletionOfAllTasks:tasks] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
    if (task.error == nil) {
        // all downloads succeess
    }
    else if (task.error != nil) {
        // failure happen one of download
    }

   return nil;
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason some requests seem to vanish is that you define `AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest` as a property. `self.downloadRequest1 = nil;` is executed on the background thread, and it is possible that when `[transferManager download:self.downloadRequest1]` is executed, `self.downloadRequest1` is `nil`.

You should remove the property and simply pass an instance of `AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest` as an argument for `- downloadFiles:`.